# What is a leaky mode of a waveguide?

Tags: optics, fiber-optics, waveguide, photonics

I know that in a waveguide is possible to distinguish between guided modes and radiative modes.
For example, in a planar waveguide, a guided mode is oscillatory inside the core and vanishes exponentially in the cladding while a radiative mode is oscillatory everywhere.

Recently I have read about leaky mode which are defined as

> modes having an electric field that decays monotonically for a finite distance in the transverse direction but becomes oscillatory everywhere beyond that finite distance. (Wikipedia)

But I struggle to find an example of these modes in a simple cases as the planar or rectangular ones.

What is an example of a leaky mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get modes like these is to have a finite 'barrier' that the light can tunnel through:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here you have an inner core of glass surrounded by an air gap (which maps, via the quantum mechanical analogy, to a finite potential-energy step) and then surrounded by more glass. Here the inner core is bounded enough to support a guided mode, but that mode is relatively 'big' and it has a substantial evanescent wave in the air surrounding the inner core, which then gets to the outer mass of glass and propagates freely.

In quantum-mechanical language, these are known as 'resonances' of the (unbounded) well.

Answer (score 0):

A leaky mode is not a true mode of the waveguide, it is rather a many wavelengths long controlled coupler/radiator *along* the axis of a waveguide. Let me quote Elliott:"ANTENNA THEORY AND DESIGN", page 453:

> "A waveguide mode typically propagates at a phase velocity greater than the speed of
>   light. If the waveguiding structure which supports this mode is properly "opened up,'"
>   the energy contained in the mode can be leaked to the exterior region, resulting in
>   what is called a leaky wave antenna. In practice, one wishes to govern the rate of
>   leakage to achieve a desired aperture distribution. With the aperture many wavelengths
>   long, the leakage rate is everywhere low and the phase velocity of the leaky
>   mode differs but little from the phase velocity of its nonleaky counterpart. As a consequence,
>   there is a quasi-uniform progressive phase distribution to the aperture distribution,
>   corresponding to the passage of a fast wave over the aperture. Thus such
>   structures are also called fast wave antennas."